# Understanding Rect in Android

Tags: android

I am trying to study the coordinate system in Android.

I want to know why does a negative sign appears in X coordinate value for right side.

Total width of rectangle  should be 100px.( See image with id 'image').

The result of rectangle is :

```
Rect(20, 95 - 120, 195)
```

My **xml layout file** :

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10px"
    android:layout_marginTop="10px"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10px"
      android:layout_marginTop="10px"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


     <ImageView 
         android:id="@+id/image"
         android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
         android:layout_width="100px"
         android:layout_height="100px"
         />

     </LinearLayout>
     <ImageView 
         android:id="@+id/image2"
         android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
         android:layout_width="100px"
         android:layout_height="100px"
         />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Show some code, how are you getting this `Rect` value?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. It is actually (x1,y1), (x2,y2). The hyphen symbol is just a separator.

Comment: The hyphen wasn't a separator, it was a subtraction, thus a syntax error because the constructor doesn't take 3 parameters.

Comment: I used 'getglobalvisiblerect()' method for imageview and passed a Rect variable. The output with hyphen is the output of the rect which I got in result.